# How to enable dynamic links to open thickbox in Google Map balloon?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, jquery, thickbox

I'm using following code to open thickbox for dynamically generated anchor tags, but it doesn't work for the first time, but second time it works.

```
function createMarker(point, InnerAddress) {
 //Other Code
var strFBUserID = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);

GEvent.addListener(strFBUserID, "click", function() {
    strFBUserID.openInfoWindowHtml(InnerAddress.split('$$')[0]);
    tb_init('a.gmapthickbox');//works second time
});

allmarkers.push(strFBUserID);
return strFBUserID;
}
```

It seems tb_init fires before, openInfoWindowHtml, any way to solve this issue? I tried setTimeOut but no success. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening to the `infowindowopen` event on your map instance before calling `tb_init`. It should be fired once the content is ready in the DOM.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.infowindowopen

Comment: Thanks @Dave for replying. I did check infowindowopen event, but I solved my problem using below code :
    var strFBUserID = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
    var openFnCallback = function() { tb_init('a.thickbox'); };
    GEvent.addListener(strFBUserID, "click", function() {
        strFBUserID.openInfoWindowHtml(InnerAddress.split('$$')[0], { onOpenFn: openFnCallback });
    });
Once again thanks. :)

Comment: Oh good idea, I'd forgotten about `onOpenFn` – that's a much smaller change to your existing code.